# Bluetooth LE on iOS cannot work with many services and characteristics

Tags: objective-c, node.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I develop a BLE application, using Core Bluetooth in my iPhone app.
My iPhone communicates with linux with bleno launched. 
The problem is that it cannot work with more than one characteristic or service, though just one characteristic works nice.
Here is my code for iOS and .js code for Node.js:

http://pastebin.com/k5pUrbLt
http://pastebin.com/biCWLmJ3

Thank you!

P.S. That's what i get in console:

2014-07-24 13:18:02.819 lexy[142:60b] didDiscoverPeripheral 

2014-07-24 13:18:04.503 lexy[142:60b] didDiscoverServices

2014-07-24 13:18:04.506 lexy[142:60b] D61191C0-FCE8-4F5A-912C-15EE39D927B4

I.e. I successfully discover and connect to the peripheral, but I do not find any characteristics. In that case I have one service with many characteristics.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate a specific problem or error message you are receiving. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask a good question

Comment: Have you tried the light blue app from the App Store to verify that your peripheral is advertising as you expect

Comment: Yes, I've tried it both on my Mac and my iPad. On my Mac it sees all the services and characteristics, but Light Blue on iPad cannot connect to peripheral. GATTT on my linux sees all the characteristics correctly. And nRF Master on Android sees everything.

Comment: Make sure you are running ios 7.1 on your iPad and try restarting it

Comment: It is running iOS 7.1.2. You think it is a problem with iPad?

Comment: I've tried it on iPhone 5s also, and it is just the same situation.

Comment: Then I would suspect the Linux code. The BLE on iOS is pretty reliable in 7.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it works on Ubuntu 14.04, but doesn't work on OpenSuse 13.1.

Answer (score 0):

iOS can work with multiple characteristics and multiple services on a remote device.

Your ObjC code seems okay (1 service with 2 characteristics).

Console output suggests that you send a discoverCharacteristics request but that it hangs and never returns. You could add logging to the didDisconnectPeripheral delegate method to see if there is a disconnect happening.

What you could also do is to look at the logs of the Bluetooth stack and to compare them to how the logs look like if you access a TI Sensor Tag (those tags are the hello world of BLE).

iOS 7.1 instructions for Bluetooth logs are located [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2014/Mar/msg00032.html), for iOS 8 you'll have to resort to Apple's official way to get the logs (installation of a configuration profile) but their logs contain less information than the ones by BluetoothCompanion.